# Debian 7, ICMPv6: RA: ndisc_router_discovery failed to add default route

Tags: linux-networking, ipv6, debian-wheezy, linode

I'm running Debian 7 and trying to configure static IPv6 addresses…

I'm getting this error message in /var/log/kern.log every few seconds.

```
Apr 27 09:25:30 orion kernel: ICMPv6: RA: ndisc_router_discovery failed to add default route
Apr 27 09:25:35 orion kernel: ICMPv6: RA: ndisc_router_discovery failed to add default route
Apr 27 09:25:40 orion kernel: ICMPv6: RA: ndisc_router_discovery failed to add default route
Apr 27 09:25:45 orion kernel: ICMPv6: RA: ndisc_router_discovery failed to add default route
```

I have followed this tutorial but can't seem to get it working.
https://linode.com/docs/networking/linux-static-ip-configuration/#debian

Here is my current: /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0

iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fe37:92b1/64 
    gateway fe80::1 

iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2600:3c00:e000:01d8::1/64

iface eth0 inet static
    address 104.237.137.8/24
    gateway 104.237.137.1
```

I have completed a reboot and the IPv6 addresses the ifconfig shows:

```
philip@orion:~# sudo ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f2:3c:91:37:92:b1
          inet addr:104.237.137.8  Bcast:104.237.137.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2600:3c00:e000:1d8::1/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::f03c:91ff:fe37:92b1/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fe37:92b1/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:37970 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:31070 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:8795804 (8.3 MiB)  TX bytes:18187830 (17.3 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:26708 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:26708 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:11657907 (11.1 MiB)  TX bytes:11657907 (11.1 MiB)
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone finds this post there was a simple answer. RA was trying to tell my server there was an IPv6 gateway so when I removed:

gateway fe80::1

And restarted things came back how they were expected to.

RA in IPv6 talk stands for Router Advertisement. Where the router(s) in the network, well, advertise that they're there and ready to route your packets to the networks they specify.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Yes, don't set your own default gateway because if you do then the incoming `ICMPv6 RA` from your router can't set it and you get that `ndisc_router_discovery failed to add default route` error message.  Delete your gateway and wait for your router to re-send the RA to set your default gateway.  When it happens, it will look something like this (note the `proto ra`):  
`default via fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx dev eth3 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1796sec hoplimit 64 pref low`